Pairwise comparison for contingency tables in R?
I have a contingency table like this in R:
Input:
data <- matrix(c(2, 20, 16, 7, 20, 23), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE,
                       dimnames = list(G1 = c("A", "B"),
                                       G2 = c("1", "2", "3")))

Output:
      G2
      1  2  3
 G1 A 2 20 16
    B 7 20 23

I applied a chi-square test and also a fisher test. Now, I want to perform a pairwise comparison inside each level for each group. For example:
For level A in G1, is there a difference between 1 and 2 in G2? At the end, I want to be able to have a table like this for:
G1-A:
Contrast | p-value
1-2         xxx
1-3         xxx
2-3         xxx

G1-B:
Contrast | p-value
1-2         xxx
1-3         xxx
2-3         xxx

I tried different packages in R, but none of them give me what I want. Am I trying something that doesn't make sense? Or could anyone help me with how to calculate this, please?

For advice on whether this makes sense or not, the question is better asked on cross-validated.  The precise answer will depend on the question you are attempting to answer, but I suspect the most likely answer is "no, it does not make sense", not least because you make no mention of multiplicity.  What you are asking to to do, can be done (though most likely not in a single line of code), but I fear it may not be wise to do it.

This depends on what the denominator is. There are 38 total in G1-A. If you are asking whether there is a way to compare 2/38 as a proportion to 20/38 as a proportion, you could do prop.test(c(2, 20), c(38, 38)). Whether it makes sense to do so probably requires a bit more context and is better asked over at CrossValidated

"chi-square test and also a fisher test. Now, I want to perform a pairwise comparison inside each level for each group.". Why? Is there any research question? To my eyes this appears as significance fishing or whatever it is called.

@Friede: p-hacking?

@AkselA Yes. ;)

would think the analogous post hoc test is lapply(1:3, function(x) fisher.test(data[, -x])) but the global test isnt significant so skip it
